# How to iterate through all parameters in a neural network using pytorch

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

I have the following simple fully-connected neural network:

```py
class Neural_net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Neural_net, self).__init__()
        self.fc1    = nn.Linear(2, 2)        
        self.fc2    = nn.Linear(2, 1)
        self.fc_out = nn.Linear(1, 1)      
        
    def forward(self, x,train = True):
        x = torch.tanh(self.fc1(x))
        x = torch.tanh(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc_out(x)
        return x

net = Neural_net()
```

How can I loop through all the parameters of the network and check if for example they are greater than a certain value? I am using pytorch and if I do:

```py
for n,p in net.named_parameters():     
       if p > value:
       ...
```

I get an error since `p` is not a single number, but rather a tensor of either weights or biases for each layer.

My goal is to check if a criterion is satisfied for each of the parameters and flag them e.g. with `1` if it is or `0` if it is not, storing it in a dictionary with the same structure as `net.parameters()`. Yet, I am having trouble figuring out how to loop through them.

I thought about creating a parameter vector:

```py
param_vec  =  torch.cat([p.view(-1) for p in net.parameters()])
```

and then accessing the parameter values and checking them would be easy,but then I can't think of a way to go back to the dictionary form  to flag them.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Hi Katerina, could you prepare a small piece of code to generate a toy example of `net`? This way StackOverflow users can help you better to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would define the criterion as an operation on a tensor. In your case, this could look like this:

```py
cond = lambda tensor: tensor.gt(value)
```

Then you just need to apply it to each tensor in `net.parameters()`. To keep it with the same structure, you can do it with `dict` comprehension:

```py
cond_parameters = {n: cond(p) for n,p in net.named_parameters()}
```

---

Let's see it in practice!

```py
net = Neural_net()
print(dict(net.parameters())
#> {'fc1.weight': Parameter containing:
#>  tensor([[-0.4767,  0.0771],
#>          [ 0.2874,  0.5474]], requires_grad=True),
#>  'fc1.bias': Parameter containing:
#>  tensor([ 0.0405, -0.1997], requires_grad=True),
#>  'fc2.weight': Parameter containing:
#>  tensor([[0.5400, 0.3241]], requires_grad=True),
#>  'fc2.bias': Parameter containing:
#>  tensor([-0.5306], requires_grad=True),
#>  'fc_out.weight': Parameter containing:
#>  tensor([[-0.9706]], requires_grad=True),
#>  'fc_out.bias': Parameter containing:
#> tensor([-0.4174], requires_grad=True)}
```

Let's set `value` to zero and get the dict of parameters:

```py
value = 0
cond = lambda tensor: tensor.gt(value)
cond_parameters = {n: cond(p) for n,p in net.named_parameters()}
#>{'fc1.weight': tensor([[False,  True],
#>         [ True,  True]]),
#> 'fc1.bias': tensor([ True, False]),
#> 'fc2.weight': tensor([[True, True]]),
#> 'fc2.bias': tensor([False]),
#> 'fc_out.weight': tensor([[False]]),
#> 'fc_out.bias': tensor([False])}
```

Comment: This solves my problem, thank you so much! it looks like my reputation is not enough yet to give it an upvote unfortunately:)

Comment: I was also wondering, having created the dictionary cond_parameters, is it possible to use it to split the network parameters into two groups, based on whether the corresponding entry in cond_parameters is True or False?

Comment: It sure is, but you need a rule to define if each entry is True/False, since many entries have tensors of dim>0.

Comment: Feel free to ask a new question, I'll do my best to solve it too :) (And you may get enough to upvote)

Comment: Thank you:) I will give it a go and will open a new question if I am having trouble.